# xlwings ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am trying to execute a python script from an excel sheet using Xlwings, however I have been getting the following error in Excel:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Excel_3'
Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

My Python script in very simple:

```
import xlwings as xw

    def main():
        wb = xw.Book.caller()
        sheet = wb.sheets('Sheet1')
        sheet['A12'].value = "Called from VBA"
```

And the code in Excel is the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RunPythonCode()

    RunPython ("import Excel_3;Excel_3.main()")
 
End Sub
```

Anyone any idea what I could do to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `Excel_3` supposed to be?  Is your file called `Excel_3.py`?  Do you know what directory it's running in?

Comment: Yes - 'Excel_3' is the name of the python file, which is saved here: C:\Users\natu\PycharmProjects\ExcelPlugin\Excel_3.py. The excel file is saved here: "C:\Users\natu\Desktop\ExcelPlugin\Excel_6.xlsm".  do the files need to be saved in the same folder? Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: Python is going to look for the import from whatever the "current directory" is.  You might consider copying the file into your Python's `...\lib\site-packages` directory.  That way, anyone can find it.